# AS3 cacheAsBitmap questions?

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, bitmap

I'm a bit confused. If I import a png picture, drag it onto my stage, and right click > convert to bitmap. Is that the same thing is if I have a vector created in code, and then apple `cacheAsBitmap = true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PNG picture is a raster object, and it has a parent class of Bitmap already. You might, however, encapsulate that Bitmap into a drawn rectangle (effectively making a rectangle with bitmap fill, that is actually a vector object), and then convert to bitmap, applying `cacheAsBitmap = true` to the vector object made of the raster object. I don't understand why do you want double transformation raster->vector->raster in the first place. Probably Flash isn't so stupid if you just drag a library asset made out of a PNG to the stage, it'll make you a Bitmap based object instead, and "convert to bitmap" won't do a thing.